# "Что-то, подобное чему-то,..." — почему обособляется?

Tags: пунктуация

Отредактировал тут предложение в другом ответе (поставил запятые):

> Явление же, подобное русскому, также существует в некоторых языках...

И понял, что мне очевидно, что выделять запятыми это нужно, но я не понимаю, почему нужно. *"Подобное"* вроде ведь прилагательное, не причастие, верно?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ну и что? Разницы нет, причастный оборот или прилагательное с зависимыми словами. Главное, что определительный оборот стоит после определяемого слова.
http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=127

Comment: Спасибо большое, Людмила! Теперь буду знать, что это называется "определительным оборотом". ;)